# python -c "print calculation" gives syntax error

Tags: shell-script, python, variable

I was doing some bash scripting and adding some python for float calculations like divide, deductions

When I am executing this, all part is running fine but for some python part it is showing me an error, however, in the latter part, it is showing me correct calculations.

```
File "<string>", line 1
    print 0.05-
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<string>", line 1
    print /2
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My script is like the following:

```
tx_fee=0.0001;
panda_txfee=$(python -c "print $check_t_balance-$tx_fee");
panda=$(python -c "print $panda_txfee/2");
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do those variables have actual values? An unassigned variable expands to the empty string, which this looks like. (I assume you have `$check_t_balance` set somewhere?)

Comment: yes, at the begining I declared all the variables with either int or float values

Comment: If I set `check_t_balance=1` and run your code, I get `$panda` as `0.49995`.  I think you're just not setting the `check_t_balance` variable.  Also, Python is a bit heavy weight just for doing floating point arithmetics in the shell.  Either use something less heavy, such as `bc`, or do it all in one single Python program.

Comment: If I did not set the variables, how it is calculating everything fine after the error? 
```Sending now.... 0.02495 to two addresses
0.02495 is sent to two zksnark addresses```

Comment: I see, thank you. Problem is, the servers I am working on do not have bc built in, so I have to check first if it contains bc then install and then run. Since, python comes built in, was wondering to use python here. I might just change it back to bc then if you say so

Comment: Do I have to assign variable everytime I have a new function? I declared all the variables globally.

Comment: To answer questions about possible problems with your variables we would have to see how you set the variables, what you do with functions etc. You should try to create a minimal script that reproduces the problem.

Comment: for your division problem see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-division-keeps-rounding-down-to-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works:

```
> tx_fee=0.0001;
> panda_txfee=$(python -c "print $check_t_balance-$tx_fee");
> panda=$(python -c "print $panda_txfee/2");
>
> echo $panda
-5e-05
```

Your errors show that variable `panda_txfree` is empty:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    print /2
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and it is empty because of `tx_fee` is empty:

```
File "<string>", line 1
    print 0.05-
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

provide more details of your environment.

Also note, I'm using Python 2.7 (and Bash), for Python 3 you will need embrace `print` arguments in round parenthesis, like this: `print($panda_txfee/2)`, because in Python 3 `print` is a function, not special keyword for printing out.

Comment: Tonight I am offline from that unix now, I will post it tomorrow.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 as well. I think, I found the mistake, I did a silly spelling mistake, Everywhere I used the variable tx_fee but only in one place I wrote tx_fees, I will test it tomorrow. I hope this was the main and only reason of this error. 
I was thinking, I have many floats so is it better to wrap it within float function like this? or its just useless?
```amt=$(python -c "print(float($amt_aft_txfee/2))");```

Comment: @RakibFiha, you can omit `float()` if value in your `amt_aft_txfee` variable goes with point, e.g. `2.5` or `2.0` also note, that in Python usually used `Decimal` (from module `decimal`) wrapper for precise calculations

Comment: @RakibFiha, In python 2, you might want `float(x)/2`, since `x/2` would round/truncate the result if `x` is an integer. `float(x/2)` doesn't help in that, the conversion happens too late there